# Invalid Private Key Format

Tags: private-key

Apologies in advance if this is a silly question but I can't figure out why my metamask private key is 66 characters long instead of 64? I'm attempting to use this key with the MakerDao Dai.js library and getting an error of "Invalid Private Key Format" its failing on this check - [github](https://github.com/makerdao/dai.js/blob/dev/packages/dai/src/eth/accounts/factories.js#L6)

What am i missing?

Comment: You're missing `0x` at the beginning of it.

Comment: but wouldn't that make my private key too long? it's already at 66 chars, that would make it 68

Comment: just tried prepending `0x` and still getting the same error - is the private key that metaMask exports valid?